# Heterogeneous Couchbase Cluster

Tags: couchbase

I would like to run a couchbase cluster on a hardware cluster that's not uniform. Some of the machines have 1 CPU core, while the others have 16 cores.

Is there a way to configure the bucket size or request frequency so the larger servers can receive a larger percentage of the load?

What I'm looking for is something similar to the [weighting in ketama](https://github.com/RJ/ketama), but for Couchbase.

Comment: I have a few questions, why do you want to run such machines with such a broad performance range?  Each node has to have the same amount of ram, so you will find that as a limiting factor.  As the data is distributed evenly between nodes you are kinda defeating the point of couchbase. Plus 4 cores or more are the couchbase recommendation.

Comment: I want a small instance always available, but to add large ones to deal with load. The requirement for each node to have the same amount of ram is basically about the bucket size being uniform, which I would like to change.

Comment: But you are talking about a huge disparity in server types 1 core to 16 core. 3 nodes is generally the base recommendation, run 3 lower powered nodes.  What sort of data volumes are you expecting? Constantly scaling up and down is going to require lots of rebalancing  operations. I don't recommend it.

Comment: Usually 1 small instance and 4-20 large ones. The small one basically only exists for cluster discovery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't method that does what you want. Keys in CB throws its own hash-function mapped to VBuckets, and VBuckets mapped to server. Couchbase API doesn't allow managed this mapping. All you can do is determined by the id of document server that owns this document.

Comment: So there's no way to ask for a server to take a greater percentage of the vbuckets? I understand theirs a VBucket-to-server table, all I really want is to have some servers occur with different frequency. Ketama supports this weighting, AFAIK.

Comment: No, there isn't such possibility. I suggest that this option could greatly complicate rebalancing operation and decrease performance.

Answer (score 1):

You stated in a previous answer that:

```
Usually 1 small instance and 4-20 large ones. The small one basically only exists for cluster discovery.
```

What you should really do is connecting to your Couchbase cluster through a [reverse-proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) (such as [Haproxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/)) instead of a constantly-up node. The reverse-proxy will have all the potential nodes in its pool, constantly looking for which nodes are really up, and dispatching connections to those nodes. As soon as a node goes down, the connection will be re-established to an alive node.

You can read more about this architecture description on [the Couchbase documentation](http://docs.couchbase.com/moxi-manual-1.8/#data-channel-versus-management-channel).